# Pass java.lang.Object as Parameter

Tags: java

I know that passing a an Object is not a good practise. But in this case it seems the best solution to me.

```
public void doSomething(final Object obj) {
    // some code
    ...
    if (obj instanceof InputStream) {
            document = PDDocument.load((InputStream) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof File) {
        document = PDDocument.load((File) obj);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument must be an instance of " + InputStream.class.getName() + " or " + " " + File.class.getName() + ".");
    // more code
    ...
    }
}
```

An alternative solution would have more duplicated code (all the line before and after `PDDocument.load(obj);`)

```
public void doSomething(final InputStream obj) {
    // some code
    ...
    document = PDDocument.load(obj);
    // more code
    ...
    }
}

public void doSomething(final File obj) {
    // some code
    ...
    document = PDDocument.load(obj);
    // more code
    ...
    }
}
```

Due to the duplicated code I prefer the first solution.

**Do you know any better solution to solve this problem?**

Comment: mix them up. have two separate methods that call a shared method with the duplicate code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in the result of

```
PDDocument.load(specificallyTypedVariable)
```

as a parameter to the method.

---

This assumes that `// some code` isn't doing some kind of setup for the `load` call. If that's the case, you could pass in a `Function<? super T, PDDocument>` along with the `T` you're going to load it from:

```
public <T> void doSomething(final T obj, Function<? super T, PDDocument> loader) {
  // some code
  PDDocument document = loader.apply(obj);
  // other code.
}
```

and invoke like:

```
doSomething(someFile, PDDocument::load);
doSomething(someInputStream, PDDocument::load);
```

Comment: I would use this idea, 3 methods (the two with specific param that will instanciate the document and call the third private accepting the `PDDocument document` that will have the full logic), simple and correctly typed. I guess this is your idea behing this answer.

Comment: @AxelH the idea here is the Law of Demeter (principle of least knowledge). The method doesn't need to know if the document is loaded from a file, read from a stream etc: it just needs the document. It is notable how only passing the thing you need makes the code simpler (just 1 method required) *and* more flexible (you could `doSomething` to documents from a wider range of sources).

Answer (score 1):

Since `PDDocument` can load from an `InputStream` and you can obtain an `InputStream` from a `File` anyway, I'd suggest:

```
public void doSomething(final InputStream in)
{
    // some code
    document = PDDocument.load(in);
    // more code
}

public void doSomething(final File file)
{
    try (
        final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    ) {
        doSomething(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Of course, handle errors accordingly!

---

Also, I don't understand why you don't return the `document` and put that processing in a method returning `void`?

Comment: nit: "A variable declared in a resource specification is implicitly declared final (§4.12.4) if it is not explicitly declared final." Making it explicitly final is merely noise, IMO :)

Comment: Maybe add the "...some code..." parts to the `InputStream` overload to make it more clear as to how this reduces the code duplication.

Comment: A slight variation on this idea would be: don't provide an overload for `File` at all: just make it so you've got to pass in an `InputStream`; caller can decide how to do that.

Comment: @AndyTurner hmm... I didn't know that :) I'll remember that. I'm a little too much `final`-happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
// some code
...
document = PDDocument.load(obj);
// more code
```

to a separate `private` method which can only be called by the two above methods